# MongoDB syncingTo change

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3 members replica set version 2.6.1 with following configuration

```
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "10.125.16.22:30000",
                    "priority" : 2

                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "10.125.16.22:40000"

                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "10.125.16.22:60000",
                    "priority" : 0,
                    "slaveDelay" : 3600,
                    "hidden" : true
```

And i want `id:2` to sync from `id:1`.

I execute

```
db.adminCommand( { replSetSyncFrom: "10.125.16.22:40000" } )
```

and got

```
"syncFromRequested" : "10.125.16.22:40000",
"prevSyncTarget" : "10.125.16.22:30000",
"ok" : 1
```

But on rs.status the sync is still `syncingTo : "10.125.16.22:30000"`

I found on documentation:

> Changed in version 2.4: The sync target falls more than 30 seconds
>   behind another member of the replica set; the mongod will revert to
>   the default sync target.

Is this what happened in my case? if yes is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information here to know if the "sync target falling more than 30s behind" was the case, but it seems likely if you are pushing through a lot of activity with all of your replica set nodes on the same machine.

There should be some log entries confirming the change; if you're still on 2.6 you should be able to grep for:

```
 changing sync target because current sync target's most recent OpTime is
```

One thing to note is that `rs.syncFrom()` is a temporary change. By default the sync targets are automatically chosen by MongoDB, and will be reset if you restart instances or lose connectivity.

There's a helpful open source tool called [Edda](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/28053108398/edda-a-log-visualizer-for-mongodb) which you can use to process MongoDB log files and visualise changes in replica set history. NOTE: The github repository has changed since that blog post was published; the current repo is [10gen-labs/edda](https://github.com/10gen-labs/edda/).